# Limit of a mixture of binomial distributions

Tags: markov-chains, probability-limit-theorems, large-deviation-theory

Let $0 < r \leq 1/2$ and let $B(n,p)$ be the notation for binomial distribution. 
Consider the random variable $Z_n$ defined by the recursive equation 
$$
Z_{n+1} = Z_n +  X_n I(Z_{n} \geq r n^2) +  Y_n I(Z_{n} < r n^2) 
$$
and 
$$
Z_1 \sim B(1,r)
$$
where $X_m \sim B(m,p_1)$ and $Y_m \sim B(m,p_2)$ and $I(\cdot)$ is the indicator function.

How to compute the probability distribution of $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{Z_n}{n^2}$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps there is a typo, or I made a simple error: Since $E[Z_n] = O(n)$, it appears that $E[Q]=0$, where $Q$ is the RV whose distribution you wish to calculate. Since the pmf $f_q(q)=0$ for $q<0$, then does this not mean that pmf is $f_q(0)=1$ and zero otherwise?

Comment: Dear @Dean,  you are right $E[]Z_n] = O(n)$, so the limit $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{Z_n}{n^2}=0$. But what happend if $Z_{n+1}$ is the accumulation of previous $Z_{n}$, i.e. $Z_{n+1} = Z_n +  X_n I(Z_{n} \geq r n^2) +  Y_n I(Z_{n} < r n^2)$. I am going to change the question for a second time.